# erase area of plot matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

Below you can find some simple code for a very simple plot.

```
y=[1 1.2 1.3 1.2 1.4 1.5 1.3 1.7 1.8 1.9 1.7 2]';
x=nan(size(y));
for i=2:length(y)
   if y(i,:)<y(i-1,:)
     x(i,:)=(y(i,:)-y(i-1,:))/y(i-1,:);
   end
end
plot(y);
hold on
bar(x);
```

This will create the plot of picture 2, where I was wondering if there is a way that I could erase the red area from zero until a point "c" as it is shown on that picture and finally obtain the plot of picture 3.

[image]

[image]

Thank you,

Marios

Comment: You can use multiple `axes` with aligned `position`s and defined `ylim`s. Or you can use BreakAxis: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/3668-breakaxis

Comment: It seems like a bad idea to have the axis not map uniformly to your values... why not use `subplot` instead?

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, if I use ylim then I can only exclude a part where it starts from the beginning or it ends in the end of the graph. For example, I could exclude the part that belong to (-0.5,c), but not only the part that belongs to (0,c). I am not sure if BreakAxis could help and subplot is not an option for me here. :)

Comment: @MariosMariolito That's the second part of the task. At first assign line plot to axes `ax(1)` and bars to `ax(2)` Then you can use `set(ax(1),'ylim',...)` and `set(ax(2),'color','none','xtick',[],...` to fit your needs. To set parameters of both axes use `set(ax,...)`. You shall also set appropriate `ytick` and maybe `yticklabel` properties as well.

Comment: @Dan I think he has two different data sets with different scales. If he wanted two lines he would look for `plotyy`.